# camel data source not available

Tags: java, apache-camel, datasource

Running a standalone java exe for testing. Camel 3.20.5

```
 private static DataSource setupDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        ds.setUsername("xcccc");
        ds.setPassword("xxxxx");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxx:1521:xxxxx");
        return ds;
    }
```

... in main ...

```
  CamelContext camelContext=new DefaultCamelContext();

     DataSource ds = setupDataSource();
        SimpleRegistry reg = new SimpleRegistry();
        reg.bind("ds",ds);
```

in Route:

```
 .to("sql:select 1 from dual?dataSource=ds");
```

Error:

```
 sql://select%201%20from%20dual?dataSource=ds due to: Error binding property (dataSource=ds) with name: dataSource on bean: sql://select%201%20from%20dual?dataSource=ds with value: ds
```

Comment: Do camelContext.getRegistry().bind(...

Comment: @SebPerp - Tried that also and not working either. same error.

Comment: Please give the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

In the route :

```java
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    private final DataSource routeDataSource;

    public MyRoute(DataSource routeDataSource) {
        this.routeDataSource = routeDataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure() {

        getCamelContext().getRegistry().bind("ds", routeDataSource);

        from("whatever").to("sql:select 1 from dual?dataSource=ds");

    }

}
```

In main:

```java
public class MySpringBootApplication {

    private static DataSource setupDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        ds.setUsername("xcccc");
        ds.setPassword("xxxxx");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxx:1521:xxxxx");
        return ds;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyRoute myRoute = MyRoute(setupDataSource());

    }

}
```